# storing temporary image in variable in the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

In my view I'm retrieving image from the database like this

```
 <img width="50" height="50" alt="" src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Properties", new { id = Model.Id })" />
```

where mvc controller returns image. Now I want in the view to store this image in some variable. How to declare this var for this kind of data.

Html source after returning image `<img height="50" width="50" src="/Properties/GetImage/77" alt="">`